# Node.js Вывод строк rows

Tags: node.js, cookie, сессия

пытаюсь использовать rows, но передавать хочу не одну строку, а десяток. Использую Express-Session
Если у меня такое действие с выборкой с запроса БД.

```
client.query (select name,last_name from pupil) where name = '$1' and 
last_name = '$2',[req.session.user2.rows[0].name,req.session.user2.rows[0].last_name]
```

При таком вводе оно работает, а когда стараюсь использователть методы

```
req.session.user2.rows.forEach(row => console.log(row.name)) 
req.session.user2.rows.map(row => console.log(row.name))
```

Оно в консоль выводит, а так не работает.

Comment: Совсем непонятно написано. Как не работает то?
Вам нужно выполнить скрипт для каждого из user2?

Comment: В общем нашел Ваш второй вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
req.session.user2.rows.forEach(row => {
       client.query (select name,last_name from pupil) where name = '$1' and 
       last_name = '$2',[row.name, row.last_name]
    })
```